# Reading result from C API call

Tags: lotusscript

I thought I could use the C API to get the public key from the users ID-file. Found the functions and think I understand most of it. But I do not get how to read the data from the address that points to what I want.

```
Declare Function W32_OSLockObject Lib "nnotes.dll" Alias "OSLockObject" (Byval handle As  Long) As Long
Declare Function W32_OSUnlockObject Lib "nnotes.dll" Alias "OSUnlockObject" (Byval handle As Long) As Long

Declare Function SECKFMGetUserName Lib "nnotes" (Byval strReturnUserName As String) As Integer
Declare Function SECKFMGetPublicKey Lib "nnotes.dll" (Byval strUserName As String, Byval intFunction As Integer, Byval intFlags As Integer, handle As Long) As Integer


lret = SECKFMGetUserName(hUserName)
lret = SECKFMGetPublicKey(hUserName, 0, 0, hPublicKey)

aPublicKey = W32_OSLockObject(hPublicKey)
```

And now what? The sitting duck is waiting for me to get it at the address `[aPublicKey]`. Have tried several ways to get the string from that address, but I fail over and over again.

It should be simple, but I have no more clue to follow.

I know there is abook to buy about the C API, but do I need a book to get a string from a known address?

Care to be my C API hero?

Comment: Why do you need to get the public key from the ID file?  It's public.  You can get it out of the Domino Directory.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to "LotusScript to C API Programming Guide", I have the book.  I highly recommend it.  There's a nice chapter on memory handling.

Try declaring OSLockObject to return a LMBCS string, like this:

```
 Declare Function W32_OSLockObjectStr Lib "nnotes.dll" Alias "OSLockObject" (Byval handle As  Long) As LMBCS String
```

If SECKFMGetPublicKey is returning a buffer containing a null-terminated string, it should work.  If not, there are other techniques that are covered in the book.